# Facebook makes emoticons graphical — how to disable this behaviour?

Tags: facebook, firefox, user-interface, configuration

Facebook started turning emoticons used in comments on status updates graphical:

[image]

How do I turn off this behaviour? Preferably inside Facebook, but otherwise with a user-side script or user-side stylesheet? I'm using Firefox (version 11 at work, 15 at home).

Comment: I only see them on the comments; not the status updates.

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves setting some Custom CSS in FB Purity, go here for the full method:

[How to hide facebook smileys / emoticons with FB Purity. Full list of codes.](http://www.fbpurity.com/news/facebook-now-displays-graphical-smileys-in-comments-heres-the-full-list-and-how-to-revert-to-text-smileys-if-you-want/)

***Update*** N.B The latest version of the FB Purity browser extension now has a built in option to turn off the graphical emoticons, so the Custom CSS is no longer required.