# How do I make this smiley on Facebook comments?

Tags: facebook

This one:

[image]

I really want to use it!

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33236/facebook-makes-emoticons-graphical-how-to-disable-this-behaviour You may have to clear your browser or log out or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Simply type `8-)` or `8)` or `B-)` or `B)` in your comment.

Here are some links for more smiley emoticons:

1. [New Facebook emoticons & chat pictures](http://fsymbols.com/facebook/smileys/)
2. [Yahoo Messenger emoticons](http://messenger.yahoo.co.in/features/emoticons/)
3. [The Smiley Dictionary](http://www.csh.rit.edu/~kenny/misc/smiley.html)
4. [All Facebook Emoticons](http://www.allfacebookemoticons.com/emoticons/)

Comment: This is incorrect. This is the emoticon with glasses.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now supports new set of smileys in comments and statuses. Actually it's only available on iPhone or Android phone using 'Emoji' keyboard... But still you can use these emotions without any smartphone by simply copy/pasting this small box or this symbol: '  '
in your comment box.

Here is the link for more smileys like these:

- [Spice up your Facebook Comments with New Range of Smileys](http://www.sociobits.org/2013/05/how-to-add-new-emoticons-emoji-to-facebook-comments.html)